# Uploading a file to a SharePoint Document Library Sub Folder using a C# Console Application in 2023

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-upload, console, document

I've been scraping the Internet for two weeks using various different solutions given but none of them work in 2023. Most of the solutions provided are old and they do not work with the new libraries and also because of the added security features such as MFA. Also almost all the given solutions threw some kind of error and various people have suggested various different workarounds in comments to get those fixed. So I've been scanning these threads as well trying various different options but after failing, finally thought of posting it here so this would be useful to someone who is facing similar issues.

Why Console app: Because I want to use the Task Scheduler to automate this and run it once per day. Have used other means such as syncing with One Drive but it creates duplicate files every now and then. So thought of using a robust mechanism such as a C# console app but have tried PowerShell scripts as well hoping I will be able to ask the Task Scheduler to run PowerShell scripts on a schedule, but none of them worked.

Just to narrow it down

- I have disabled MFA
- Even tried using an App password (Yes I managed to generate the app passwords successfully, but won't work with C#, always some kind of error, after fixing one you get another but after some point you come to a point where there are no resources on how to fix those errors)
- I'm using SharePoint Developer site to test it out at the moment.

Example site URL could be: https://5mhhvs.sharepoint.com
Created a site called Documents: https://5mhhvs.sharepoint.com/sites/Documents
So my goal is to upload a file regularly to a sub folder in the Document Library of the Documents site.

Wondering if someone can provide a sample code, together with the package names I need to configure using NuGet and the necessary using statements (as there can be conflicting namespaces) either using username/password approach or app password (ClientID/Secret).

Other queries: If there is already a file, will it merge the changes or is there a setting we can configure so that it will merge the changes.
If a user has opened the file on SharePoint (and may be has started editing), will we still be able to upload the file or can we force it?

Hope someone will be able to put an end to end solution here instead of posting links to previous posts.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's two parts in order to answer your question, Authentication and actual file upload.

For the first part i will have to redirect you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74077387/8894067) where I had explained in depth a couple of ways that you can authenticate against and AAD tenant.

One of the projects uses MS Graph Authentication (it does not authenticate against SharePoint directly) so my intension was to update the code of that project since it's just a plain console app.

So in order to demonstrate a simple use of the file upload methods I have generated an App Registration in my dev AAD and handed out MS Graph Application Permissions `Sites.FullControl.All` and `Files.ReadWrite.All` in order to implement the `Client Credential Flow`.

Just a reminder, you can read about the certificate generation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#setting-up-an-azure-ad-app-for-app-only-access).

For the next part, most of the relevant code can be found [here](https://github.com/jimas13/SPSyncer/blob/master/ConsoleAppMSGraph/Program.cs#L58C13-L58C13):

```
    //get Id of root site of sharepoint
    var site = await graphClient.Sites["root"].Request()
                                    .GetAsync();
    //get lists of the root site
    var filteredLists = await graphClient.Sites["root"].Lists
                                    .Request()
                                    .GetAsync();
    //filter out default Shared Documents Library from all of the lists of the Site
    var library = filteredLists.FirstOrDefault(tempList => tempList.DisplayName.Equals("Documents"));
    
    //define a file name
    var fileName = "SampleTextFile.txt";

    //define a file path
    var filePath = Path.Combine("C:\\path\\to\\document.txt");
    
    //open up stream for file contents
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        if (library is not null)
        {
            //get a target of the specified folder or better yet Drive.
            var targetFolder = graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[library.Id].Drive.Root;
            // Upload a file
            var uploadedItem = await targetFolder.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

[image: generated file is located in sharepoint library]

Now utilizing the `GraphServiceClient` is typically straight forward and the above way of uploading files to sharepoint is permitted for [files that are less than 250 MB.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

If you wish to achieve a uploading a file that is more than 250MB then [you will have to create an upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0), where the general idea is the same and well documented in microsoft docs.

For last, there's another way where you can explore uploading a file to SharePoint through the MS Graph Endpoints and that is located in the [Graph Explorer site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

You can try generating a link as it is documented in the [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#to-upload-a-new-file)
It should look like this:

`PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content`
and have the contents of the file in the body of the request as plain text, alongside a header for `Content-Type` set to `text/plain` (or else you will get a 400 response)

And beware that the id's of objects that you get back from the Graph Endpoints might be really strange, but they are still the ids :P
[image: graph exporer generated upload]

Comment: Also it is possible to generate sharepoint migration manager scripts that initiate migration tasks and typically upload tons of files to SPO, but that's mostly reserved to one-off SPO migrations tacticts. Anyway, you can check it here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/overview-spmt-ps-cmdlets

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?